# Creating an Overworld portal to a specific location in the Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been reading the Wiki lately and have read some interesting facts about portals. One thing in I was interested in was the teleportation aspect.

First thing I did with success is placing the old portal I had in a different location. I didn't like the location at all,

I did the following.

- Build the new portal in the Overworld.
- Wrote the coordinates and calculated where the new portal should be ( x/8 | z/8)
- I broke my old portal, and used the new one to teleport to the nether
- In the Nether I broke the old one, and build the new one as close to the right spot
- Went back and came out in the new portal

Worked out great.

Now I have only been playing MC for about 2 weeks, so the next thing I want to do is a little bit too chalanging for me.

### Question

I have a nicely working Blazefarm in the Nether, but it is a kinda danerous walk. I wonder if I can create a portal near my base which will instanly TP me to the location.

Basically I want to build a portal in the Nether at:

```
Nether: X: -70/71; Y: 72; Z: -139
```

Now if I make the calculations I will **end up way too far in the overworld**.

I will end up at:

```
Overworld: X: 560; Y: ? Z: -1112
```

But my main portal, and base are at:

```
Overworld: X: 180/181; Y: 50; Z: 340
```

That's a hell of a journey for me.

### Suggestion

I wonder if the following would work.

- I build a new portal in the overworld more than 128 blocks from my old one
- I fire it
- I go trough my old portal to the Nether
- I build my new Nether portal close to my blazefarm
- fire it and go trough it

Will I then end up and the new portal in the overworld?

I am planning to build the Overworld poral at:

```
New Overworld portal: X: 220/221; Y: 12; Z: 200
```

The Z coordinate is now more than 128 blocks away from the old one.

Comment: Those coordinates can't be all that far from your existing nether portal - just make a safer way to walk there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The short answer is no.** When You enter the a portal from the nether, on your way to the overworld, Minecraft calculates the primary portal coordinates with this generalized equation:

```
{X, Y, Z} → {floor(X) × 8, Y, floor(Z) × 8}
```

The game then checks for an active portal in a 128 block radius around that location. Given your nether portal coordinates:

```
X: -70; Y: 72; Z: -139
```

Your overworld portal must be within the following horizontal bounds:

```
X = -688, -432
Z = -1240, -984
```

Remember, any overworld portals *within 1024 blocks of each other* will link to **the same nether portal**, because 1024 blocks in the overworld = 128 blocks in the Nether, and the game checks for portals in a radius of 128 blocks.

If you build a new nether portal at the blaze farm and destroy your old portal, your main base portal will probably link up to your blaze farm. However, when you attempt to go back to the overworld, Minecraft will look for a portal within the above bounds and create a new one if it doesn't find one.

Your best option is probably to build a rail line from your current portal to the blaze farm. Ghasts can destroy any block with a blast resistance below 20.17, but they won't shoot at you without a line of sight, so you can make an inexpensive safety-tunnel around  your rail line with pure Netherrack.

You can also build a more scenic tunnel with stone, glass, leaves, fences, etc, since Ghasts cannot "see" through transparent blocks.

Comment: Don't use Netherrack for a Ghast-safety tunnel. If they see you, one shot will make a huge hole. I'd use Cobblestone or something of equal blast resistance. Ghasts can't see through slabs, so you can make windows that way.

Comment: Thanks guys, I already thought it was too good to be true. I just just relocate my portal to a good spot so the trip to the spawner is not as dangerous. When I have time on my hands I will build a safe route.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can utilize is "hidden" or at least generally "off/on" portals. It takes a bit of creativity to get it working just the right way, but it can totally produce results and can allow you to have multiple portals in a small area all leading to different things.

See my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245142/my-nether-portal-keeps-spawning-a-new-one-when-i-go-back-from-the-nether/245148#245148) for an example of how I used it in a functional situation, as well as additional info related to linking portals, in the context of that post. In the context of yours here is the relevant info copied over:

> In one of my worlds (Xbox 360) I have an underground pyramid. At the top of the pyramid is a portal which anyone will find on their way down from the overworld. If they enter this portal they go to the nether hub, if they enter the portal in the nether hub they return to this top portal.
>
> I have this or a similar design (one of Mumbo's probably) nearby in my pyramid: (linked below)
>
> This hidden portal actually turns /off/ as you teleport. It takes you to a secret room BELOW the nether hub portal. Taking the portal out of there...well the portal you took to get in is hidden/turned off so it "doesn't exist" and the game will want to create a new exit portal for me, but I purposefully placed it close enough to the "normal" portal that instead of creating a new portal close to where the "hidden" one is it just sends you to the former.

- Different ratios for portal linking depending on world size (I believe this only affects console versions of the game as the PC is default to "unlimited" map size with the 8-1 ratio):
  http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/728000-minecraft-playstation-4-edition/70175025
- Some linking concepts (try other videos; no one seems to cover ALL the caveats):
- Something I used in conjunction with creative linking to build "hidden" transportation systems:

Comment: While I agree that "x rep to comment" idea is bad and only causes non-answer answers, we can't do anything about it. I think that this is a ok answer and is ok like this. But I'd recommend adding contents that apply to this question of that answer here.